# Chrome opus file playback from FTP

Tags: html, google-chrome, ftp, mime-types, opus

I've been trying to make chrome play opus audio file throught HTML5 audio tag by giving it source of php script. 
This works fine in mozilla, but chrome gives an error "*Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/ogg*".

```
<td>
  <audio preload='none' id='$row[FILE_NAME]' controls='controls'>
  <source src='../../functions/play.php?FILE=$row[FILE_NAME]' type='audio/ogg; codecs=opus' />
  </audio>    
</td>
```

Here's the code of the script which downloads audio file from ftp

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["FILE"]) && ($_GET["FILE"]!=""))
{
    $FILENAME=$_GET["FILE"];
    $ftp_server = "server";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to    $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'username', 'password');
    $fsize = ftp_size($ftp_conn, $FILENAME);

    header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$FILENAME.'"');
    header('Content-Type: audio/ogg');
    header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);

    $path = "ftp://username:password@server/".$FILENAME;

    $handle = fopen($path, "rb");

    if (FALSE === $handle) exit("Failed to open stream to URL");

    $contents = fpassthru($handle);

    fclose($handle);

    print ($contents);
}

else exit("No filename recived");
?>
```